# Change popup notification timeout?

Tags: gnome, notification

Ubuntu 18.04 Gnome

I'd like to change it globally for the whole system and not on a per app basis. Currently it seems like they NEVER timeout and I have to stop what I'm doing to close them.

I was thinking maybe there's a way with dconf?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, the [notification timeout cannot be changed](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=783719). It is actually not a fixed timeout. "if you move the mouse up towards the notification, the timeout is prolonged, and notifications do not hide when hovered."

However, it is possible to disable Notification popups. This way, it won't disrupt you, but it still remains available in the notification area you see when clicking the date or by pressing <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd>.

To disable notification popups, head to "Settings" - "Notification".

Comment: Thanks. I'll just have to do that then. Is this unique to Ubuntu or the Gnome DE in general?

Comment: That is Gnome Shell in general. Link I showed was someone filing an issue to allow changing the timeout, so exactly your question.

Answer (score 3):

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3795/notification-timeout/

This extension worked perfectly for me trying to tackle the same problem. Apart fromthis, there seems to be no other way in setting or dconf.

Comment: There's also the extension [Shell Configurator](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4254/shell-configurator/)

Answer (score -1):

You said that the notifications never timeout. That can be changed by heading over to Notifications, and then checking/enabling the option that states 'Remove notifications after their timeout is reached'.

Comment: There is no such option